ProcessPoolExecutor hangs without completing while the same function completes in a loop in 80mins, no errors
I have a function which loads PDF files and processes them and returns some information. When I run the function in a loop it takes close to 80mins to complete.
for filepath in glob.glob('*.pdf'):
    doc = fitz.open(filepath)
    extract_info(doc)

Since the process does not depend other previous files, i believe I can parallelize this. I did so using ProcessPoolExecutor
with ProcessPoolExecutor(8) as executor:
    with tqdm(total=num_files) as progress:
        futures = []
        for filepath in glob.glob('*.pdf')
            doc = fitz.open(filepath)
            future = executor.submit(extract_info, doc)
            future.add_done_callback(lambda x: progress.update())
            futures.append(future)

        res = [future.result() for future in futures]

I was observing task manager and I can see in the beginning there are 8 processes working and after a while most of them go to 0% CPU util and holds a bit of RAM. One process seems to still work which holds a bit more RAM. I have been watching for 4 hours, and it does not seem to complete.
Any pointers are welcome! Thanks!
Followed this https://gist.github.com/alexeygrigorev/79c97c1e9dd854562df9bbeea76fc5de

out of memory exception handling is poor, i think it is now stuck, maybe run it again with only 6 or 4 workers, and see if that succeeds.

you may need to check your future objects for errors. Something inside fitz or extract_info may be incompatible with multiprocessing. Also good to add the if __name__ == "__main__": gaurd to any process creation. It's not strictly necessary on linux, but good practice anyway.
